# Symfony SwiftMailer: not sending if the controller does not return a $this->render() response

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, swiftmailer

I have a Symfony project which (very simplified) looks like this:

*Controller/MyToolController.php*

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Services\ToolsService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class MyToolController extends AbstractController
{
    private $toolsService;


    /**
     * @param ToolsService|null $toolsService
     */
    public function __construct(ToolsService $toolsService = null) {
        $this->toolsService = $toolsService;
    }

    public function run() {
        // some more code here...

        $mailContent = $this->render('site/mail.html.twig', $data)->getContent();
        $this->toolsService->sendMail($from, $to, $bcc, $mailContent, $subject);

        // if I remove the following line, no emails are sent out!
        return $this->render('site/thankyou.html.twig', $data);

    }
}
```

*Services/MyToolService.php*

```
namespace App\Services;

class ToolsService
{

    /** @var \Swift_Mailer */
    private $mailer;

    /**
     * @param \Swift_Mailer $mailer
     */
    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function sendMail($from, $to, $bcc, $body, $subject) {
        $mail = ( new \Swift_Message() )
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setBcc($bcc)
            ->addPart($body, 'text/html');

        $res = $this->mailer->send($mail);
        $this->logger->info('Email sent');

        return $res;
    }
}
```

If you look at `MyToolController.php` you see that I call a service which sends the email.

If I return a `Response` object in my `run()` function, everything goes well - but if I omit this, nothing is sent. Same if I send multiple emails in a loop and I run into a timeout.

Strangely `$mailer->send()` is called in any case - and it returns 1 - and I see an entry in the log I am writing in the `sendmail()` function. But no email leaves the server.

This is my SwiftMailer configuration:

```
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

Comment: What's your  swiftmailer configuration?

Comment: Spooling mail could definitely cause this. Along with the fact that swift sends mail responding to the Kernel End event of Symfony

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε - Kernel End event? That sounds interesting - do you have more information on this? Thanks!

Comment: @Gerfried my memory was not fully correct, the right event is [kernel terminate](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-terminate-event) as pointed by yivi's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mails are  being  spooled  in memory, [which means](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/email/spool.html#spool-using-memory):

> When you use spooling to store the emails to memory, they will get sent right before the kernel terminates. This means the email only gets sent if the whole request got executed without any unhandled exception or any errors.

If you do not return a `Response` object from your controller, there *will* be an unhandled exception, the whole request *won't be executed*, and the mails will never be sent.

Controllers need to return a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` so the request can be handled normally. If you want to return an empty response, you can simply do:

```
return new Response();
```

Comment: But in the UX perspective, serving a blank page would seems broken really, better `$this->redirect('somewhere')`

Comment: Considering the OP wanted to omit returning a response at all, I imagine that’s not their concern.